# My drop down menu isn't displaying the drop down portion of the menu in Chrome/IE

Tags: html, css, web, menu

I have recently added a drop down menu to my website... well, in the works of adding a drop down menu to my website. I have the list displayed horizontally but the drop down portions of the list are not.. dropping down. I was wondering if someone would be able to take a look and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks, here is my code.

HTML

```
<ul id="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Apparel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gloves</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Punching Bags</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Protection</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Wholesales</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Equipment Catalogue</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wholesale Inqueries</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Direct Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">YouTube Channel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LinkedIn Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook Page</a></li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
#main-nav,
#main-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#main-nav {
    float: left;
}
#main-nav > li {
    float: left;
}
#main-nav li a {
display: block;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#main-nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
z-index: 999;
}
#main-nav ul li a {
    width: 80px;
}
#main-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
/* Main menu
------------------------------------------*/
#main-nav {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #880202;
}
#main-nav > li > a {
    color: #fffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#main-nav > li:hover > a {
    background: #c90000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* Submenu
------------------------------------------*/
#main-nav ul {
    background: #880202;
}
#main-nav ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#main-nav ul li:hover a {
    background: #c90000;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this code in you code and check

```
 <ul id="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Apparel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gloves</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Punching Bags</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Protection</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wholesales</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Equipment Catalogue</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wholesale Inqueries</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Direct Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">YouTube Channel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LinkedIn Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook Page</a></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
```

li tag is over after the sub menu ul tag

Comment: You sir, are awesome. I was going crazy. Thank you very much.